# tmux not printing ANSI colors in status bar

Tags: osx, tmux, colors

I'm using Mac OSX Yosemite, and I use `istats` to get CPU temperatures:
[image: istats_output]

I wanted to put my CPU temperature in my tmux status bar, so I made my tmux config the following:

[image: tmux_conf]

As you can see, when I ran `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf`, tmux is printing the ANSI codes as text, rather than rendering the colors. How do I make tmux render the color codes, rather than printing them out as text?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by writing a simple python script to replace the ANSI codes with tmux color variables.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

s = raw_input("")

s = s.replace('\x1b[32m', '#[fg=colour10]')
s = s.replace('\x1b[93m', '#[fg=colour11]')
s = s.replace('\x1b[0m', '#[fg=colour255]')

print s
```

I just pipe the output to the script: `istats | grep "CPU temp" | ansi2tmuxcolors.py`

Answer (score 0):

I generalized Subliminalmau5 answer by writing a separate shell with

```
sed -r 's,\x1b\[38;5;([0-9]+)m,#[fg=colour\1],g'|sed -r 's,\x1b\[1m,#[bold],g'|sed -r 's,\x1b\[0m,#[default],g'
```

which translated all 256 colors of ANSI to tmux.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little perl script to convert ANSI color escape codes to TMUX color escape codes: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SimonLammer/dotfiles/0a0828b1a7583968a5f8e65f2f31c659562c3ece/data/tmux/scripts/ansi-colors-to-tmux.pl

```
#!/bin/perl -nw

# This converts ANSI color escape sequences to TMUX color escape sequences,
#   which can be used in the status line.
# Example: "\x1b[31mERROR\x1b[0m" -> "#[fg=red,]ERROR#[default,]"

# The following SGR codes are supported:
# - 0
# - 1
# - 30 - 49
# - 90 - 97
# - 100 - 107

use warnings;
use strict;

my @colors = ("black", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "cyan", "white");
while(/(.*?)(\x1b\[((\d+;?)+)m)/gc) {
    print "$1#[";
    my @sgr = split /;/, $3;
    for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#sgr; $i++) {
        if ($sgr[$i] eq "0") {
            print "default";
        } elsif ($sgr[$i] eq "1") {
            print "bright";
        } elsif ($sgr[$i] =~ /(3|4|9|10)(\d)/) {
            if ($1 eq "3") {
                print "fg=";
            } elsif ($1 eq "4") {
                print "bg=";
            } elsif ($1 eq "9") {
                print "fg=bright";
            } elsif ($1 eq "4") {
                print "bg=bright";
            }
            if ($2 eq "8") { # SGR 38 or 48
                $i++;
                if ($sgr[$i] eq "5") {
                    $i++;
                    print "colour" . $sgr[$i];
                } elsif ($sgr[$i] eq "2") {
                    printf("#%02X%02X%02X", $sgr[$i + 1], $sgr[$i + 2], $sgr[$i + 3]);
                    $i += 3;
                } else {
                    die "Invalid SGR 38;" . $sgr[$i];
                }
            } elsif ($2 eq "9") {
                print "default";
            } else {
                print $colors[$2];
            }
        } else { # Unknown/ignored SGR code
            next;
        }
        print ",";
    }
    print "]";
}
/\G(.*)/gs;
print "$1";
```